# R - how to subtract with rowsum

Tags: r, rowsum

my dataframe looks like this.

```
df <- read.table(text="
                 column1  column2   column3
    1            3        2         1
    1            3        2         1 
", header=TRUE)
```

I need to subtract last 2 columns from first. For counting that columns I´d use `rowSums(summary[,1:3])` but I don´t know how to subtract this columns.  Note that I can´t just write my code like this since I don´t know column names.

```
`result <- df %>% 
mutate(result = rowSums(column1, - column2, - column3))`
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can subset the data to remove the first column (`.[-1]`), get the `rowSums` and subtract from 'column1'

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
    mutate(result = column1 - rowSums(.[-1]))
#   column1 column2 column3 result
#1       3       2       1      0
#2       3       2       1      0
```

If there are more columns and want to select the last two columns

```
df %>%
    mutate(result = column1 - rowSums(.[tail(names(.), 2)]))
```

---

If we have only the index of the columns that are involved in the operation

```
df %>% 
    mutate(result = .[[1]] - rowSums(.[c(2, 3)]))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(column1 = c(3L, 3L), column2 = c(2L, 2L), column3 = c(1L, 
 1L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Comment: But what if I know just index of that column1 but now its name?

Comment: @Sklenicka  In that case use that as a vector i.e. `df %>% mutate(result = column1 - rowSums(.[c(2, 3)]))`

Comment: Are you saying that you know only index of all the columns.  Then try `df %>% mutate(result = .[[1]] - rowSums(.[c(2, 3)]))`